# How i can find the average value of a column ,when it is Sunday?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, average

I have 3 columns.

```
customer(varchar),timestamp(date),consumption(integer)
```

I want to find the average consumption for all customers when it is Sunday.

[image: I done this but i dont get any result]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please replace the pointless image with the text of your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PostgreSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html you should use EXTRACT and DOW function as in example: `SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');`

It returns you the number which is equivalent to day of week where 0 is Sunday.